# mysql - Query to find out which ones i dont have?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok I have a table people and I have and Id column with thousands of record... I have another list of comma seperated Ids like this

```
1, 2, 457, 558, 998
```

I want to check this people table to see which of the 5 records is not present...

I tried

```
select id from people where id not in (1, 2, 457, 558, 998)
```

but this returns all the other thousand records and not just the records not found in these 5

any ideas what i am missing

Comment: change `not` to `IN`, and in the (5) results; just check which one you're missing.

Comment: no i need the records out of the 5 that are not present in the people table...so for example if 1, 2 and 998 are in the people talke already then i need 457, 558 returned and thats all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.id
from (
    select 1 as id
    union all
    select 2
    union all
    select 457
    union all
    select 558
    union all
    select 998
) a 
left outer join people p on a.id = p.id
where p.id is null
```

If the values you want to check against are in a table, you can do this:

```
select c.id
from MyCheckValues c
left outer join people p on c.id = p.id
where p.id is null
```

Comment: I cant use this approach because i have 3000 i need to check on - I need the records out of the 5 that are not present in the people table...so for example if 1, 2 and 998 are in the people talke already then i need 457, 558 returned and thats all...

Comment: @Trace That's what my query does.

Comment: but I have 3000 records i need to verify and i cant do  select 1 as id union all for each one

Comment: The `UNION` is only used for the 5 values you are checking against.

Comment: my question is just an example of what i need to check on .....i have 3000 not 5... I just didnt want to paste all 3000 in my question

Comment: @Trace Where are your 3000 values stored? If they are in a table it is much simpler: see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
Select id from people where id in (1, 2, 457, 558, 998)
and id not in ( select id from people )
```

Comment: This finds all the matching...not the ones that dont match...thats what i need

Comment: this should give you any record in the supplied list, EXCEPT the ones that are already in the people table.  (those that do not match) - unless i am missing your initial question.

Comment: no i need the records out of the 5 that are not present in the people table...so for example if 1, 2 and 998 are in the people talke already then i need 457, 558 returned and thats all...

Comment: no this gives me records that are in the people table already....maybe u have it backwords

Comment: Actually, this query will never return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM people WHERE id IN (1, 2, 457, 558, 998)
```

If you have multiples of each "id", then use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM people WHERE id IN (1, 2, 457, 558, 998)
```

Comment: From the question: "Query to find out which ones i **dont** have?"

Comment: If he puts $arr = array(1,2,457,558,998);  then queries above to get another array, then a simple comparison in the script will give the result he needs.  Of course that's not a pure SQL answer, but is what I had in mind.  Not sure whether your query or this would be faster performance wise.   He'd have to use some scripting language to build your query unless it's a one-shot deal.